# ::Hover on option works with IE but not with CDHtmlDialog

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I am using `CDHtmlDialog` and want to change the highlight color of option. I added a key to the  Windows Registry

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]

"HtmlDlg.exe"=dword:00002af9.
```

I am using IE11 and in CSS added 
    option:hover {background:#000;}
also in my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>        
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
```

the HTML works fine with IE11 but on the dialog option:hover have no effect.

Comment: Where did you include your CSS files?

Comment: right after .js files    <script src="D:/Dev/HtmlDlg/HtmlDlg/ajax/JS/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="D:/Dev/HtmlDlg/HtmlDlg/ajax/JS/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="D:/Dev/HtmlDlg/HtmlDlg/ajax/JS/jcarousel.ajax.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="D:/Dev/HtmlDlg/HtmlDlg/ajax/CSS/style.css">        
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="D:/Dev/HtmlDlg/HtmlDlg/ajax/CSS/jcarousel.ajax.css"> </head>

Comment: use a relative path instead, you can't load local resources like this.

Comment: To use the relative path I need to use navigate. And I do not want an external HTML page. So I am using absolute path. But even I tried relative path too. But no success. I want to know whats special about the browser and what I am missing here in CDHtmlDialog. Do i need to implement something to make :hover, :focus, :active work for  select>option in CDHtmlDialog.

Comment: You need to include css files, your path src="D:/Dev/HtmlDlg/HtmlDlg/ajax/JS/jquery.jcarousel.min.js" simplely won't work! Use relative path to your current html file. If you want to use absolute path, use src="/HtmlDlg/HtmlDlg/ajax/JS/jquery.jcarousel.min.js", given that /HtmlDlg/ is your root for www.

Comment: i used  <base href="file://D:/Dev/HtmlDlg/HtmlDlg//"> to use relative path but still :hover is not working for select option tag

Answer (score 0):

An answer was posted on https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/b262d61c-9c46-4f9f-ab14-a6af7406d36c/hover-on-option-works-with-ie-but-not-with-cdhtmldialog?forum=iewebdevelopment

> Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab>check "Allow active content to run in files on my computer" and "allow active content to run in CD's'
>
> or
>
> add the mark of the web to your pages.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(v=vs.85).aspx
>
> hint: not all clients will map their cd/dvd drives to d: